# get the single parameter in URL in javascript

Tags: javascript

**what i need** to get single "parameter" from a "full url" in Javascript like the example below :

example :

```
http://cms.example.com ----> cms
```

What i have done till now and tried windows.location.href.split('.');

Javascript code

```
var y =  window.location.href.split('.');
var z = y[0];
console.log(z); //output  http://cms
```

here output is not coming what i needed can anyone help?

thanks in advance.

Comment: read on this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Comment: it wont work... i have tried this is something different

Comment: If your own solution almost suits you, why not doing `substring` to your result? Maybe something like `if( z[ 4 ] == 's' ) z = z.substring(0, 7); else  z = z.substring(0, 6);` ( the test is in case you have https instead of http )

Comment: window.location.href.split('.')[0].split('//')[1]      this  will give final result .. Are you try it.. @adasdasd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `location.host` as it doesn't have the protocol. It's worth to mention that this method is not reliable. If you don't have `www` or a subodmain, the root domain will be returned (like in the snippet below)

```js
var y =  window.location.host.split('.');
var z = y[0];
console.log(y);
console.log(z); //output  http://cms
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location.host.split('.')[0]
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/host)

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` you could try this one:

```
s.split("//")[1].split(".")[0]
```

where `s` is your string. In the first `split`, we split the string on `//` and we take an array of two items, the second item is the domain name. Then splitting the domain name on `.` you get an array of it's parts and the first item is that you are looking for.

```js
var s = "http://cms.example.com";
var r = s.split("//")[1].split(".")[0];
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
window.location.href.split('.')[0].split('//')[1];
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13418727)

Comment: Its Working fine @ppeterka

Comment: I didn't question that. Please read the help on how to post answers. Without any explanation, this only qualifies as a _comment_.

Comment: Ok thanks... @ppeterka .. But i will give explanation if questioner don't know about jquery function like split ,window.location.href etc..